# How can I draw a plot in negative y direction in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

[image]

I want impact graph to be started from the 0 base line and expand it in the negative y direction.
So in highcharts there is option like to set min and max to range the axis. But it dosen't work accurately. The y axis c I want this to be in the negative side as its value will be in negative percentage values.

```
chart: {
    // type: 'column',
    zoomType: "xy",
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      categories:['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
      crosshair: true,

    },
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      // Primary yAxis
      min:0,
      labels: {
        format: "{value} In Million $",
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: "A",
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        },
      },
      opposite: false,
    },
    {
      // Secondary yAxis,
      min:0,
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        text: "B",
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        },
      },
      labels: {
        format: "{value} In Million $",
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        },
      },
      opposite: true,
    },
    {
      // Tertiary yAxis
      min:-0.1,
      startOnTick: -10,
      endOnTick:-10,
     ,
      title: {
        text: "C",
        style: {
          color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        },
      },
      labels: {
          format: '{value} %',
          style: {
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
          }
      },
      opposite: true,
      credits: {
                    enabled: false
                }

    },
  ],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
  },
  series: data,
};
```

I also specified threshold option to true in data series

```
data.forEach((item) => {
      if (key == "A") {
        obj["name"] = key;
        obj["type"] = "column";
        obj["yAxis"] = 0;
        obj["threshold"] = 0;
        obj["data"].push(item[key]);
        obj["tooltip"]["valueSuffix"] = "In Million $";
      }
      if (key == "B") {
        obj["name"] = key;
        obj["type"] = "column";
        obj["yAxis"] = 1;
        obj["threshold"] = 0;
        obj["data"].push(item[key]);
        obj["tooltip"]["valueSuffix"] = "In Million $";
      }
      if (key == "C") {
        obj["name"] = key;
        obj["type"] = "column";
        obj["yAxis"] = 2;
        obj["threshold"] = 0;
        obj["data"].push(item[key]);
        obj["tooltip"]["valueSuffix"] = "%";
      }
    });
```

I want something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `top` and `height` properties to position the axes in the way you want.

```
    yAxis: [{
        height: '50%'
    }, {
        top: '50%',
        height: '50%',
        offset: 0,
        opposite: true
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wrzLqsju/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.top

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.height